# How to change the text color in Chris Banes' Android-PullToRefresh Library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I'm currently using this library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

By Chris Banes to implement pull to refresh in my app and I'm having trouble customizing the text color and size in my app. I noticed that in the README Chris gives a rough, quick guide on how to customize your app but I don't understand it. Is the stuff in the attrs.xml file supposed to go as attributes in my layout file? How do I change the background color to blue, for example?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!